# jQuery contextMenu initialize on right click event

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using contextMenu plugin from: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/

I want to show the contextMenu on each cell of a table when its right clicked. THe table has a large number of cells so I dont want to initialize the contextMenu on every cell on $(document).ready().

I want the contextMenu to be initialized dynamically on each cell, only if its right clicked. Below is my code:

```
$('td').mousedown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 3) {
        $(this).contextMenu({
            menu : 'contextMenu'
        },
            function (action, el, pos) {
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "test.aspx/GetData",
                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType : "json",
                data : "{ 'TableId': '" + $('#table').id + "'}",
                success : function (response) {
                    if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(response.d)) {
                        // do something
                    } else {
                        alert('No Data Found');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

This code works but the contextMenu shows only on the second right click on the cell. The first time I right click on a cell nothing happens; but if I right click on it again, the menu shows.

How can I make this work on the first right click?

Comment: Found this question looking for the jQuery right-click event. smh0427's use of the code here gave me my answer: `$('td').mousedown(function (e) { if (e.which === 3) {`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize this function on page load